# Mongo find RegExp not accepting array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, find

I used `RegExp` many times before this one, so I dont know why its not working. I already tried to use `$in` and `aggregate`.

**Code 1:**

```
var auxTest = req.params.n;
auxTest = auxTest.split(" ");
Proq.find({$or: [{title: new RegExp(auxTest, 'i')}]}).exec(function(err, findProq){
    //CODE
});
```

It dont find anything with this code, but when I use "Code 2" it works:

```
var auxTest = ["Link", "Mode"];
Proq.find({$or: [{title: new RegExp(auxTest[0], 'i')}]}).exec(function(err, findProq){
    //CODE
});
```

Its the first time it happens with me.
What is the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: [the `RegExp` constructor does not take an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). If you do pass one, then it will be stringified, which is essentially calling `.join(',')` on the array, so the result is `/Link,Mode/i`. You might have used arrays before but they would have worked by accident, not because the produce the correct regex you want. In fact what *do* you even want - something to match *either* of those terms (`/Link|Mode/i`) or it has to match *both* of them (`/Link.*Mode/i`)?

Comment: @vlaz Sorry, I want to match either of them, but I cant predict what those terms gonna be thats why I store them in a variable. So how do I do this with a variable?

Comment: Then just create a normal regex from the array - if you do `auxTest .join("|")` and pass that to the regex constructor, that will give you `/Link|Mode/i` which matches either. You still have to make sure each term is a valid regex parameter. Alternatively, you can generate a regex for *each* term - this could be useful for better error messages. In that case, you can simply do `var testers = auxTest.map(ter, => new RegExp(term, 'i'))`, you can then pass the input through each regex in the `testers` array and perhaps report which ones fail, as opposed to having one giant regex.

Comment: @vlaz Got it, thank you!!